# Use of the minus sign in a conditional contained in a Python list comprehension?

Tags: python, python-3.x

What does the minus sign do, inside the following list comprehension?

```
[n for n in range(1000) if n % 9 == 0 - n % 4 == 0]
```

This produces a list of multiples of 36 (between 0 and 1000), so the minus sign appears to be functioning like "and". But if you pick `n` to be a multiple of 36, both `n % 9 == 0` and `n % 4 == 0` would be `True` and therefore the literal subtraction of those two would be `0`, which I assume Python would interpret as `False` and therefore exclude `n` from the list.

I'd never seen the minus sign used in this context like this before, so I'm wondering what's going on here.

Comment: Read it as `(n % 9) == (0 - n % 4) == 0`, not as `(n % 9 == 0) - (n % 4 == 0)`.  But it's still a bizarre way to write `n % 9 == n % 4 == 0` (or even plain old `n % 36 == 0`). Where does the code  come from?

Comment: For reference, check the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence) for operator precedence.

Comment: Or just use `[*range(0, 1000, 36)]`. Is this from a code obfuscation contest?

Comment: It's from student work, LOL. I asked for a list comprehension that will find the intersection of the set of multiples of 4 and the set of multiples of 9 and this is what I got. So yes, code obfuscation all the way.

Answer (score 0):

Just use `n % 36 == 0` instead.

---

**Edit: Just realized the below is wrong.**

This code is really weird, so I guess I just subconsciously assumed it was normal. I'm keeping the text below because it's a cool fact I didn't know before.

---

As far as I can tell, this behaves like the bitwise XOR operator. It returns `True` (includes `n`) if one and only one condition is `True`:

```
print(True - False) # 1
print(False - True) # -1 (which is a True value)
print(True - True) # 0
print(False - False) # 0

# bool(A - B)
# A B -> _True__False_
# True  | False True
# False | True  False
# This is an XOR gate.
```

You could also use `^`.